# Active or Passive with 'to form'

Tags: verbs, active-vs-passive

Should I choose Passive or Active form of the verb here?

> In fact, a pool of melted water ____________ **(FORM)** at the North Pole
>   every year now since 2002.

I guess, a pool can't form itself, so Passive should be used. However, according to the keys, the answer is **'has formed'**.

I would be very happy if someone shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*to form* is used here as an intransitive verb, which has no passive form:

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/form#dictionary-entry-2):

> 2: to take form : come into existence : arise
>   // Storm clouds were *forming* over the hills.

The [present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect) is used here to indicate something that has been going on from the past until now.

I guess it's possible to use the passive here, if you indicate the actor:

> In fact, a pool of melted water has been formed by increasing global temperatures at the North Pole every year now since 2002.

but I'm not sure if it's idiomatic.

Comment: And in fact, the present perfect is used in the source from which this sentence has been taken: https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/climate-weather/stories/north-pole-melts-forms-lake-at-top-of-the-world

Comment: Thank you very much:) How do we use intransitivity to choose between Active or Passive? If the sentence 'The next government will be formed' is grammatically correct, I wonder why Passive is used there. As far as I understand, 'form' is intransitive there.

Comment: Well, using *has been formed* in your example sentence would be grammatically correct as well, but not the most idiomatic choice. It might be different because here something is formed by natural process, i.e. it forms *itself* (other Germanic languages use a reflexive verb here), while the government is being formed *by people*.

Comment: @Glorfindel can’t thank you enough:)